# How can I get the value of a checkbox and use it to update a file path

Tags: node.js

How can I change the file path of a csv file path in nodejs.
I want it to get the value of a checkbox with a corresponding name and put it here:

```
const csvFilePath = "./uploads/Core Front End -Membership Services - defects.csv";
```

instead of a hard coded file name

this is the post function that needed the variable

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath);
```

```js
router.get('/import', function(req, res, next) {
  var csvup = []
  var csvStream = fastCsv()
    .on('data', function(data) {
      var report = new csvUploads({
        jirakey: data[0],
        status: data[1],
        priority: data[2],
        validity: data[3],
        type: data[4],
        month: data[5],
        defectCategory: data[6],
        defectSubCategory: data[7]
      });

      report.save(function(error) {
        console.log(report);
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }
      });
    }).on('end', function() {});
  stream.pipe(csvStream);
  res.json({
    success: 'Data imported successfully',
    status: 200
  });
});
```

This is the radio buttons that I want to get the value from, I also want to get the value of the dropdown box\

```html
 label.radio-inline
  input(type='radio' name="team" value="CCP" id="1")
  | CCP
label.radio-inline
  input(type='radio' name="team" value="WMP" id="2")
  | WMP
label.radio-inline
  input(type='radio' name="team" value="ELT" id="3")
  | ELT
label.radio-inline
  input(type='radio' name="team" value="Central QA" id="4")
  | Central QA
label.radio-inline
  input(type='radio' name="team" value="Global Education" id="5")
  | Global Education
label.radio-inline
  input(type='radio' name="team" value="Mobile" id="6")
  | Mobile
label.radio-inline
  input(type='radio' name="team" value="Data Services" id="7")
  | Data Services
label.radio-inline
  input(type='radio' name="team" value="CA" id="8")
  | CA
label.radio-inline
  input(type='radio' name="team" value="SAP" id="9")
  | SAP
br
br
label.col-sm-4.control-label(style='color:white')
.col-sm-4(align='center')
  select.form-control.m-b(name='account')
    option Choose Month ...
    option January
    option February
    option March
    option April
    option May
    option June
    option July
    option August
    option September
    option Ocotber
    option November
    option December
```

Comment: I only needed this variable for the retireval of data

Comment: I use Jade as the template and express